# mysql_fetch_assoc variable in while loop is not working

Tags: php, mysql

Why is working?

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){...code... }
```

Why is not working?

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

while ($result){...code... }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Because the second is an infinite loop. You're just checking to see if `$result` is non-false, and never changing its values.

Answer (score 1):

because mysql_fetch_assoc return **one** item of array, not the array

> Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

assing $result if mysql_fetch_assoc() has a item, if not stop while.

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
 //....
}
```